# Generateing a method via source code in pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

My goal is to generate a test method (automatically if we can say so). To do this, I need to send to a method that I named writeTestMethod., two parameters: the method I want to generate its test method from and a set of values ​​as the second. Once I send this, writeTestMethod will generate me the test method in which there are the assertions.

In the test method, I must be able to retrieve its class from the send method as a parameter. Once done, I initialize this class with its default constructor.
And the second parameter is a set of values, with this set of values, I will initialize a new object of the same class but this time using the values.
and at the level of the assertions, I will test if the two are equal.

I have a method that allows me to build the name of a test method but I can't write in it.

```
buildSelectorFor: aMethod
    ^ String streamContents: [:i || capitalize |
        capitalize := true.
        i << 'test'.
        aMethod selector do: [:charactar |
            charactar= $:
                ifTrue: [ capitalize := true ]
                ifFalse: [ capitalize
                            ifTrue: [ 
                                capitalize := false.
                                i << charactar asUppercase. ]
                            ifFalse:[ i << charactar ]]]]
```

so if I execute this method with this for example:

```
buildSelectorFor:Car>>#speed:mark:
```

I get this:

```
testSpeedMark
```

my goal is to get something like

```
testSpeedMark
    self assert:....equals:...
```

I added a method writeTestMethod.

```
writeTestMethod: aMethod with: anObject 
    ^(self buildTestSelectorFor: aMethod),'
      |classMethod setter instObject method|
      classMethod := aMethod methodClass.
    setter := (classMethod  allSelectorsInProtocol: #setter) asArray.
    instObject := classMethod new.
    (setter with: anObject do: [:set :ivar | instObject  perform: set with: ivar]).
     self assert: instObject class equals: (classMethod new) class.'
```

So here is what I get:
[image]

I don't know how to integrate the parameters of writetestMethod in the code I want to generate

Comment: The assertion isn't interesting, it basically says that `classMethod` equals itself. I don't get your idea but suspect that it admits a simpler approach.

Comment: In fact, as indicated in the method writeTestMethod, I send two parameters: a method and an object (in my case, a set of values). Now with the aMethod method sent as a parameter, I can ask for its class then, I will rebuild another object with the values ​​(anObject) and test them with assert:...equals:...

I do this because we know that a test method does not take parameters. Hence the error in the image.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Do you have another idea please ?

Comment: I have a suggestion: edit your question and add a simple explanation of what you are trying to achieve, not about the code you have written but about your actual goal. The explanation should describe the objects you are creating, where the data comes from and what testing strategy you have in mind. Do your best to be clear and concise and people will help.

Comment: I just edited my question with explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to indicate that you have a parametric template for creating source code, in this case, source code of tests methods, and a way to generate data that should be tested with the resulting methods.

1. Write one method that receives the required parameters and answers with the source code of the desired method (it looks like you already know how to do this, see 3 bellow though)
2. Install the method in `aClass` (a subclass of `TestCase` whose name I don't know). To do this, you can use `aClass compile: source`, where `source` was obtained in step 1.
3. Add an ivar `data` to your testing class and a setter for it. Make sure that the source code generated in step 1 operates on the ivar `data`.
4. For each piece of data you happen to generate create an instance of your testing class, set the ivar `data` accordingly and add the test to a newly created `TestSuite` (use `TestSuite >> named:` for this). Here you can use `TestSuite >> addTest:`.
5. Run your suite with `TestSuite >> run`.
6. To get rid of automatically created tests, should you want to do that, send `removeSelector:` to your testing class.

Comment: My problem lies with the third point. how to do it ?

Comment: I would suggest implementing `data` as a `Dictionary` with associations `ivar -> value`, so the test can predicate on this structure using `data at: ivar`. Much as you would do with a `Json` object.

Comment: Ok i see. But when i want to install the method in `aClass` , i have the error in the image.

Comment: Copy the source code generated and try to save the method manually in the same class. That will make it easier for you to understand what went wrong.

Comment: When i try to copy the source generate, i have this error: `Unknown variable: aMethod please correct, or cancel. ` Which comes back to what is in red on the image and the origin of my problem. that I am unable to transmit the parameters that I receive from my method writeTestMethod to use them in the generated source code. As I use quotes to generate and install it via `compile: source`

Comment: Then your tests need two ivars: `class` and `data`. Set both in step 3. Then the method should be a temporary initialized as `method := class compile: source`.

Answer (score 0):

I think only you'd need to do is use: `targetClass compile: 'source code of the method you want to have'`
source code is a string, so you can just format on whatever you want, e.g. `I want to print {1}.' format: {'apples'}` would result in: `I want to print apples.`